# Editing record in SQL Server DB in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

After filling DataTable, I am trying to edit my record in SQL Database.
The code is

```
Dim dRow As DataRow
    dRow = dSet.Tables("tblTest").Rows(0)
    dRow.BeginEdit()
    dRow.Item("Name") = txtName.Text
    dRow.EndEdit()
    dAdt.Update(dSet, "tblTest")
```

But it returns error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  It comes on  `dRow = dSet.Tables("tblTest").Rows(0)`
Please advise.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can directly use like below

```
dSet.Tables("tblTest").Rows(0).Item("Name") = txtName.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

This may because you have no rows in your table (i.e. no row at position 0) or because you have no table by that name in your dataset.  You can check this in the debugger.

Can't guide you too well for the next bit without seeing how your dataset is populated.

Comment: No I have taken count of tables and records.  I have one table and three records in the same dataset.